# mongodb aggregation with list of ids

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation

I got the following aggregation:

It scans all the messages and groups them by a docId and returns only the **last** updated message in each group.

```
db.getCollection('Messages').aggregate([ { '$match': { docType: 'order' }}, { '$sort': { updatedAt: -1 } }, { '$group': { _id: '$docId', content: { '$first': '$content' }}}])
```

which returns -

```
[
{
    "_id" : "some id1",
    "content" : "some msg1
}

/* 11 */
{
    "_id" : "some id2",
    "content" : "some msg2"
}
...
]
```

It is working as intended (not sure about optimization).

But now I need to add another thing on top of that.

In the UI I got a list of documents and I need to show only the latest message for each. But I also got paging so I dont need to bring the last message for XXXXXX documents but only for 1 page.

So basically something like this -

```
.find({'docId':{$in:['doc1', 'doc2', 'doc3'...]}})   - if the page had 3 items
```

But I am not sure how to combine all of that together.

```
Message sample:
    {
    "_id": "11111"
    "docType": "order",
    "docId": "12345",   -  this is not unique there can be many messages for 1 docId
    "content": "my message",
    "updatedAt" "01/01/2020..."
    
    }
```

Comment: Not too sure. But if you know the docIds on page 1, you can just write another {$match} after {$group}. Else you can try skip() and limit() in mongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
{ '$match': { _id: { '$in': ["docId1", "docId2"]} }}
```

at the end did the trick!

edit:

or actually I think It might be better to add it as the first pipeline so:

```
db.getCollection('Messages').aggregate([ { '$match': { docId: { '$in': ["5d79cba1-925b-416b-9408-6f4429d7c107", "8e31c748-c86d-407e-8d83-9810c8e23e3e"]} }}, { '$match': { docType: 'order' }}, { '$sort': { cAt: -1 } }, { '$group': { _id: '$docId', content: { '$first': '$content' }}}])
```

- Since I am adding those dynamically I ended up with 2 $match properties. I actually not so sure what difference does it make to use $match + $and vs having 2 different $match (optimization wise).